# Display responsive list inline wider than the window

Tags: html, css

I want to make an infinite slider on my website. What I have tried to do is make an unordered list of elements where the list items will be the individual slides. I have run into problems getting the list items to display inline and allow overflow through the left and right ends of the browser while also keeping the list items responsive so that they scale down. I have tried everything I can find on SE and even asked my friend who is a full-stack developer for help with no luck.

```
<section>
    <hr class="pad2">
    <ul id="slide-show">
        <li>
            <div class="arrow-left"></div>
            <img class="world-map" src="/images/passport/world_map.jpg">
            <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="arrow-left"></div>
            <img class="world-map" src="/images/passport/world_map.jpg">
            <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="arrow-left"></div>
            <img class="world-map" src="/images/passport/world_map.jpg">
            <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>   
    <hr class="pad2">
</section>



.world-map {
    height: auto;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#slide-show {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slide-show li {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.arrow-left {
    height: 12%;
    width: 2.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    top: 44%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-right {
    height: 12%;
    width: 2.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    background-color: black;
    top: 44%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The idea is that only one of the list items will be on the screen at a time and the left and right arrows will slide the #slide-show over to allow other slides to come into view.

Comment: you need to explicitly give it a `width` in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated a few lines of the css and I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
#slide-show {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#slide-show li {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Here is a working pen: http://jsbin.com/copugojapa/1/edit

---

**Update**: here is a functional demo of the slider - you may want to replace the js with your (faster) code: http://output.jsbin.com/jorucexeza/